# I 'still not' speak Russian or I 'still don't' speak Russian?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, negation

Which of these sentences is the correct one?

> I **still not** speak Russian
>
> I **still don't** speak Russian?

Even though normally I know that verbs that describe usual or routine things get the structure of present simple, *in this case*(?) I have doubt that when using "still" it is like a "modal verb", but I'm not sure.

Comment: Still is not a modal verb. It is an adverb. "Don't" is a modal verb in this sentence and "speak" is the actual verb. "Still" describes "don't speak" to clarify that you are, at the present and also to some point in the past, not able to speak Russian.

Comment: No, *don't* is not a modal verb.  It's an auxiliary, though, which is what's important here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Negative phrases are most commonly formed with the auxiliary verb "***do***" in the negative: "***do not <verb>***".  Since 'speak' is the verb that you want to use, it needs to be preceded by "**do not**" (or "**don't**"), regardless of the other qualifiers like "*still*".

> I still **don't** speak Russian.

(BTW, while it likely means you are *unable* to speak Russian, it can also mean that you are *unwilling* to speak it)

---

There are cases when a verb can be followed by "**not**" to make a negative, but those are few.  For instance, "know" can be followed by "not":

> I *know not* what to do.

but it's mostly artistic, bookish way of saying "I **don't know**..."

Comment: I know not is a quote from Shakespeare. Don't get confused,  it isn't in anyway in modern use

Comment: It is not necessarily just from Shakespeare.  "I shot an arrow into the air, it fell to earth, I ***knew not*** where..."

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing my writers. Either way, anyone that uses it is probably referencing literary work

Comment: Though this answer is not incorrect, it's potentially misleading, imho. A quick glance through your answer made me think that you recommend saying *"I **know not** what to do"* rather than *"I **don't know** what to do"*.

Comment: Edited prompted by the latest comment.  Better?

Comment: @VictorBazarov I +1! :-)

Comment: And +1 for quoting [a poem](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/173890)! (0: